# Android studio get error "Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. Error Duplicate resources"

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-studio-import

After converting an eclipse project into android studio I am getting below error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> [string/test] E:\Workspace\Calculators\app\src\main\res\values\strings_sizing.xml
  [string/test] E:\Workspace\Calculators\app\src\main\res\values\strings_conversion.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

How can I resolve this error in Android Studio?

Comment: Did you look at either of the files in the error message and check for duplicate entries?

Comment: yes I have checked but there is no any duplicate entries ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is telling you that you have the same string resource defined in 2 different files.  The entry

```
<string name="test">...</string>
```

exists in both

- app\src\main\res\values\strings_sizing.xml  AND
- app\src\main\res\values\strings_conversion.xml

(Note that I simulated this scenario in my Android Studio environment and the build produced the exact same error message that you have posted.)

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error occurred due to the string resource in two different locations with same name.
i.e., while creating project default string resource is created.

```
<string name="app_name">Application Name</string>
```

And another same string resource manually I have declared in Gradle

```
 def appName = "Application Name"
```

So this issue occurred. To solve this issue try to keep only one resource.

This is not only applied here, anywhere in the project if we define two resources with same name this issue may raise.